# How to let partial view call the action of the controller in area using "@Url.Action"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried to let partial view(_CartPartial.cshtml)  call the   action of  the controller(OrderController.cs) in area using "@Url.Action" .

But the browser shows : Not  Found View: 'Index'.

the code shown as follows:

_CartPartial.cshtml

```
**<a id="CartDropDown" class="btn-group btn-group-lg" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Order", new { })">

</a>**
```

OrderController.cs

```
**public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Order
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index( Models.Order.Ship postback )
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}**
```

the folder shown as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you use

```
@html.ActionLink("link text", "Action Name", "Controller Name");
```